Pairing with half-sums of positive roots
While reading papers, I encounter the a problem explained as follows:
Let $G$ be a reductive group (over some algebraically closed field). Let $T \subset L \subset B \subset G$ be a sequence in which $B$ is a parabolic subgroup, $L$ a Levi subgroup of $B$, $T$ is a torus. Let $\rho_G,\rho_L$ be half-sums of positive roots of $G$ and of $L$ determined by $B$ and $B \cap L$, respectively. Let $R^{\vee}(L,T)$ denote the set of coroot of $L$ with respect to $T$.
Question: for any $\lambda \in R^{\vee}(L,T)$, why do we have $\left <2\rho_G - 2\rho_L,\lambda \right >=0$?
My knowledge on algebraic groups (or reductive group) in general is very limited so please do not assume that I know too much. Detailed answers with examples are very welcome and appreciate.

The Levi group of $B$ is the torus. If you want to have a more interesting Levi, you should replace the Borel by a parabolic.

@Sasha yes it should be parabolic, thanks.

One can also write $\rho_G$ as the sum of all fundamental weights $\omega_i$ of $G$, and similarly for $L$. On the other hand, $\langle \omega_i, \alpha_j \rangle = \delta_{i,j}$, where $\alpha_j$ is a simple coroot. Thus, $\rho_G - \rho_L$ is orthogonal to any simple coroot of $L$, and therefore to any coroot of $L$ whatsoever.

Does each fundamental weight of $L$ appear as a fundamental weight of $G$?

Each fundamental weight of (the semisimple part of) $L$ is a restriction of the unique fundamental weight of $G$.

can you give a reference of what you just wrote?
